# Batch File - Get path from registry

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I want to write a batch file that schedules a job using Task Scheduler.

This is what I've

```
schtasks /create /tn Task /tr D:\LogSender\Sender.exe /sc HOURLY /mo 1
```

The thing is that I'm not sure about the path of the sender.exe this task will execute. So  i need to read this value from the registry key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE****Framework.

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=3* delims= " %%r in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bmp\OpenWithList" /v a') do (
  set "exe_path=%%r"
  echo %%~r
)
```

Change the path to the registry you want and `/v a` with the key you want to get value.

[REG HELP](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by npocmaka will not return the correct path if the path has spaces, use the following code and make sure to replace the parameters of the reg.exe command with the correct values.

```
For /f "Tokens=2*" %%x In ('Reg.exe Query "HKLM\Software\...." /v "a"') Do Set "exe_path=%%y"
```